# how to order list that has date and a word in sql server

Tags: sql-server

```
case when prefinallist.truckbooked is null then 'Immediate' else CAST(prefinallist.previous_date as varchar) END as ETA
```

The list contain either `the word Immediate or datetime`.

How to show immediate on the top and date in acending.

Comment: I think you should add a column that has the 0 value when the `ETA` is an 'immediate' and 1 when it is a date. Then sort by this additional column and the `ETA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use ORDER BY like this:

```
ORDER BY (`ETA` = 'Immediate') ASC
```

or you can also use CASE statement inside the ORDER BY like

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ETA = 'Immediate' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

Comment: thank you @Rahul Tripathi . In the order after Immediate the datetime should be in accending order.

Comment: @Rubenrj:- You just have to append `prefinallist.previous_date asc` in the `order by` clause.